# Why doesn't the Fedora EPEL repo have Nginx v1.20.2?

Tags: nginx, amazon-linux-2

I have some Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instances.

I've installed the Amazon Linux 2 EPEL topic and the EPEL repo:

```
amazon-linux-extras install epel
```

I've installed the latest available version of nginx:

```
yum install nginx
```

The version I get is `1.20.1`.

`1.20.2` appears to have been released on November 16th, 2021. If I take a closer look I can see the EPEL repo is pointing at a fedoraproject.org repo:

Partial contents of epel.repo:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
```

If I navigate to [http://download.fedoraproject.org](http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/n/) and search through the packages, I can confirm that only 1.20.1 is available.

On my RHEL 7 servers, they all have NGINX 1.20.2. Why does this repo still not have NGINX 1.20.2 available? Am I missing something? I would like to have NGINX 1.20.2 (or whatever latest version is available at the time) installed through an available repo including future updates, on my AMZ Linux 2 instances. I do not plan on building the package or installing the .rpm manually as this sticks me at a certain version without updates.

Comment: There are commercial repositories available with the latest NGINX and more. My recommendation is to look at the [NGINX Extras repository](https://nginx-extras.getpagespeed.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Double check where you got that 1.20.2 from, with `rpm -qi nginx`  nginx's upstream rpms have a Vendor NGINX, and are built on some cloud host.  EPEL rpms are Vendor Fedora, and a fedoraproject.org build host.

As of March 2022, nginx is 1.20.1 in [EPEL 7](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/nginx), CentOS 8 modular, and CentOS 9 Stream.  (Note the switch from EPEL to AppStream.) Fedora 34 and ELN have 1.20.2.

Ask the EPEL maintainer about the minor version bump. Of the EPEL [communication channels](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/#communicating_with_the_epel_sig), the devel mailing or IRC is a start for inquiries. Then probably an EPEL issue in bugzilla to track action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I later realized I had added the NGINX repo to RHEL 7. Which is exactly what I did on Amazon Linux 2 now. So all systems have 1.20.2 now. I’m not familiar with the process of trying to get the EPEL updated. From your explanation 1.20.1 is pretty consistent across multiple platforms. I’m curious why they aren’t more up to date being 1.20.2 has been out several months.

Comment: I linked to the EPEL communication channels, ask the maintainer. Just looking the repo, difficult to say if it was intentional.